# Can I convert an std::vector into an std::tuple at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have an std::vector (with a variable number of elements) which I am trying to convert into an std::tuple for passing to another function. Is it possible to do this at runtime?

Comment: How does the vector (size) is construct ?

Comment: the vector is just the elements from a user-provided CSV. so could be 1, or 1E10 elements. But I have realised that I am doing the wrong thing here and that I need to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. A tuple is a compile-time container which contains a certain number of elements. This means that the code that handles a tuple is generated at compile time, and is dependent on the number of elements that you specified for the tuple.

At the same time, this will also be true for the function you are calling: you will be able to call it only with a specific type of tuple. Passing a reference to the vector you already have seems a better solution.

Comment: this is what I suspected, given that I couldn't find the answer easily. Thanks!

Comment: The question is about **runtime**, not compile-time, I don't know why don't you use `std::make_tuple(v[0], v[1], v[2])`

Comment: @jeremy You might be able to convert the N-first elements of your vector into a tuple, if N is known at compile time :)

Comment: @PiotrS. And I answered that it cannot be done at runtime, since the asker wanted a tuple to deal with a variable number of elements. If the vector had only a given number of elements it would have worked, of course.

Comment: @Svalorzen: then why not `template <typename... Args> void foo(std::tuple<Args...>)` so that it still works with `std::make_tuple` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Because you will still have to specify to `std::make_tuple` how many elements to insert in the tuple. Since this number is not given at compile time, the compiler cannot know what the type of the resulting tuple would be, and would not be able to instantiate `foo` either.

Comment: @Svalorzen: it is not flexible, but it's not true that "it is not possible", imagine enormously large switch that calls make_tuple depending on vector's size. actually, if it is going to be a tuple, then the vector probably is not that large enough so as not to introduce such switch

Comment: @PiotrS. If you start to imagine, you can do anything. One could even just pick the biggest tuple available and fill all unused spots with marker values, or pass along another value representing the count of useful elements (again given that the vector is bounded in size). But I don't know what the asker is going to do, I just answered his question.

Comment: @Svalorzen: no, even if you have broad imagination, you are limited by what the language constrains. saying *"you cannot"* is not true in this case, especially if you say *"I don't know what asker is going to do"*. if you don't know what OP is trying to do, just ask in comments under question, maybe the tuple is up to 5-element-length ?

Comment: @PiotrS. This may be a difference in opinion, but the question here seemed fairly concise and clear, and I answered it. I understand what you are saying, and you are welcome to post an alternative answer to mine. Without any hint to what OP is doing, I believe answering what has been asked to be more polite than trying to do all the thinking for him. If he has a more specific problem, he is also welcome to update his question. Given the info given, I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: the context to this problem is not so much that I really need to do this, but rather I haven't used std::tuple nor c++11 before and I was curious as to whether this conversion was possible or if it was indeed a compile-time only container. Thanks both for your input though.